# glitch when opening selectbox(jquery) in asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have a selectbox which contains food types. The problem is, when i try to open it, style of selectbox is not loaded at the bottom of web page. My english is not very good so i took 2 screenshots:

First i'm clicking the selectbox:
http://postimg.org/image/4r5hm13pr/

Then, i'm scrolling the page a bit lower:
http://postimg.org/image/64x4hc2z3/

As you can see, there are another elements that couldnt be seen. Their css properties were not loaded.

here is my html code:

```
      <div class="cont-data clearfix">
//some list elements here

<li>               

     <div style="float: left;">
                        <div class='long-select'>
                        <select class="pyemek" id="pyemek" style='font-size:x-small'>
                            <option />
                            <option value="AVML">Asya Vejetaryen</option>
                            <option value="BBML">Bebek</option>
                            <option value="DBML">Diabetik</option>
                            <option value="FPML">Meyve Tabağı</option>
                            <option value="GFML">Glütensiz</option>
                            <option value="HFML">Yüksek Fiber</option>
                            <option value="HNML">Hindu</option>
                            <option value="KSML">Koşer</option>
                            <option value="LCML">Düşük Kalori</option>
                            <option value="LFML">Düşük Yağ / Kolesterol</option>
                            <option value="LPML">Düşük Protein</option>
                            <option value="LSML">Düşük Sodyum</option>
                            <option value="MOML">Müslüman</option>
                            <option value="NLML">Laktozsuz</option>
                            <option value="ORML">Oryantal</option>
                            <option value="RVML">Çiğ Vejetaryen</option>
                            <option value="SFML">Deniz Besinleri</option>
                            <option value="SPML">Özel</option>
                            <option value="VGML">Vejetaryen</option>
                            <option value="VLML">Vejetaryen Lakto / Ovo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
    </div>
            </li>

//some list elements
</div>
```

this is my "long-select" class' css:

```
.long-select { position:relative; width:169px; height:27px; }
.long-select .sbHolder { background:url(../../images/core/long_select.png) no-repeat left top; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:169px; height:27px; z-index:1000; }
.long-select .sbHolder .sbSelector { display:block; width:100%; height:100%; font:12px/2em PNSemiBold; color:#FFF; text-indent:5px; }
.long-select .sbHolder .sbOptions { background:#003b75; position:absolute; left:0; top:108% !important; z-index:9999; border-radius:6px; padding:3px 0; }
.long-select .sbHolder .sbOptions li { float:left; display:block; width:100%; height:20px; padding:3px 0; }
.long-select .sbHolder .sbOptions li a { font:13px/1.2em PNSemiBold; color:#FFF; display:block; width:100%; height:100%; text-indent:8px; }
```

Any ideas?

edit: this is my another css that may be needed:

```
#section .flyListData .tableData .cont-data {
    background:#f4f4f4;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding:10px 8px;
    border-radius:6px;
}
#section .flyListData .tableData .cont-data li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Over here: .long-select .sbHolder .sbOptions { background:#003b75; position:absolute; left:0; top:108% !important; z-index:9999; border-radius:6px; padding:3px 0; } How does it know the height? is it in another div that has a fixed of absolute height? Because it seems like the part that is not resizing is in another div or something that has a fixed or absolute size.

Comment: i edited my post. added another <li> and <div> that contains this code block.